# Given that we know the exact position of an electron orbiting a proton what is the PDF of its energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Given a known amount of energy we can plot a PDF of where an electron orbiting a proton should be. Can we reverse this? If we know the exact position of an electron orbiting a proton what is the PDF of its possible energy?

I think this is sort of related to emission spectrums. The light ray emitted by each jump between orbits has an energy of $E = hf$. If we knew the energy gained or lost by jumping between each orbit we'd know the frequencies of light released by the jump. So, I think what I want is basically similar to a PDF of the frequency of light released by a specific jump in energy. I don't think that the frequencies can be exactly discrete because we can't know the exact position of an electron and its energy levels.

Comment: An electron doesn't *"orbit"* a proton, as the term PDF clearly implies. An electron 'occupies' an orbital, associated with a total energy, which is quantified to discrete levels. An electron can transit from one discrete energy level to another, with emission or absorption of a photon of energy $\Delta E=hf$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what this question is trying to ask. You *can't* know an "exact position" of the electron, there are no quantum states associated to having a fully certain position (the often used $\lvert x \rangle$ is merely a formal tool, not an actual state). However, for any actual state $\lvert \psi \rangle$ you can always compute its "energy PDF" by just computing its (squared) inner product with the energy states.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible in principle: you can express position eigenstates in the energy eigenbasis,
$$|x \rangle = \sum_{n,l,m} | n,l,m \rangle \langle n,l,m | x \rangle.$$
However, in general the expression will be extremely complicated. For example, if you really use position eigenstates (instead of some localized wavefunction $\psi(x)$), which is not really legitimate, you'll include states with arbitrarily high momentum by the uncertainty principle.

The more important point is that this is not a productive thing to do. You probably think the 'typical' state for an electron looks like $|x \rangle$ since it's "orbiting around" the proton. But if you really had such a state, the electron would rapidly radiate away energy, as you know from studying the Bohr model. In equilibrium, the state of the atom looks simple in the energy basis, not the position basis.

Comment: We hit an electron orbiting the atom with a particle and learn the position of the electron. However, by hitting the electron we excite it and so the electron reaches a higher energy level. Since, the electron's position is well known it must follow classical dynamics and decay back down to a lower energy level and release a photon. In principle, we can predict the position of the electron until it emits a photon and then we learn its energy but lose track of its position right? So, doesn't the energy PDF stuff correspond to an electron gaining or releasing energy?

Comment: No, even neglecting radiation, and assuming everything is totally perfect, you can't predict the electron's future position because it will spread out over time. It won't have a definite position.

Comment: But an electron with definite energy, ideally, stays that way. That's why we prefer the energy basis.

Comment: I won't lose knowledge of the electron's position until I gain knowledge of its energy though right?

Comment: Ah, I think I see the issue. If you know the energy of a particle, and nothing knocks it, you know its energy forever. Position is not like that! Look up wavepacket spreading.

Comment: Generally, knowledge of a quantity X is only preserved in time if X is a conserved quantity. Position is not, energy is.

Comment: How fast do we lose knowledge of the electron's position?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39483/discussion-between-steven-stewart-gallus-and-knzhou).